# Committing changes removes files from repository

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, version-control

I have recently started using git version control with Visual Studio Code.
It was all working well, and I managed to get a lot of work done, but I've just now made a change to the code, and when I tried to commit it, it just removed the file from the repository. I tried looking this up, but to no avail. I tried using the command line `git commit -m "message"` as opposed to the source control panel of VS Code, but that didn't work, and I couldn't find anything concerning this issue in the documentation.
I also tried committing the change and then using `git add --all` and `git add "filename.py"`, but neither helped, and they just staged all other files in the repository.
Does anyone have a clue why I'm experiencing this issue, and could offer some assistance?

Comment: `git status` will tell you what files have changed. If that file isn't there, it's either a) not changed (or is not new), or b) it is listed in your `.gitignore` file so git will not track it.

Comment: I see. I'll check it and update the post. Thanks!